# How to receive streamed response from KSQL in Spring Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ksqldb

How to receive chunked response from kafka KSQL server in java spring boot app?

When I make a rest call to the `/query` endpoint I just get 1 row and the connection closes. How can I keep the connection open and receive multiple rows?

The doc says

> The response is streamed back until the LIMIT specified in the
>   statement is reached, or the client closes the connection.

What's the way to achieve this in java? Even for KTable I get only 1 row in return.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/api.html#run-a-query-and-stream-back-the-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I was able to work it around is the following:

- get the response as a String
- parse JSON objects line by line (`KafkaQueryResponse` is an object that represents 1 row)

  ```
      ResponseEntity<String> result = template.exchange("/query",
          HttpMethod.POST,
          new HttpEntity<>(params, headers),
          String.class);

      List<KafkaQueryResponse> array = new ArrayList<>();
      JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
      try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(result.getBody()))) {
          Iterator<KafkaQueryResponse> value = objectMapper.readValues(jsonFactory.createParser(br), KafkaQueryResponse.class);
          value.forEachRemaining(e -> {
              if (e.getRow() != null) {
                  array.add(e);
              }
          });
      }
      array <----  this is the list of JSON objects
  ```

`KafkaQueryResponse`

```
    @Data
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class KafkaQueryResponse {
        private KafkaQueryRow row;
        private String finalMessage;
        private String errorMessage;

        @Data
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public static class KafkaQueryRow {
            private List<Object> columns;
        }
    }
```

This solution does not allow reading the streamed response in chunks. It waits for the whole response to arrive to the client, then closes the connection and then parses all json objects.